# react-native-webview on Android cannot load a local file saved on the cache directory with the ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

In my app, I download and save a file to my app's cache directory (e.g. `file:///data/user/0/.../cache/5f8f.../downloaded.pdf`) and try to open this file using WebView. My WebView code is:

```js
<WebView
  source={{ uri: file.uri }}
  startInLoadingState
  originWhitelist={['file://']}
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  allowFileAccess={true}
/>
```

On iOS, it works fine. However, on Android, it prints `ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I've tried some solutions found on GitHub and StackOverflow:

- https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/656#issuecomment-561067913

, but still not working on my case.

Any other solution to solve my problem? Thanks, in advance. If you need more code to investigate, please let me know.

== edit:
`file.uri` looks like `file:///data/user/0/.../cache/5f8f.../downloaded.pdf`. It is a file stored on the cache directory.

Comment: We cannot see the uri your webview is using. Please post more complete code.

Comment: @blackapps I added about `file.uri` in the body.

Comment: You did not provide the code i asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Webview on Android cannot display a pdf document.